# How do I compute the eigenvectors of a general matrix using the QR decomposition (PLAPACK)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working on an eigensolver in [PLAPACK](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~plapack/), which has built-in functionality to find the QR decomposition of a general matrix of double precision floating point numbers. I am familiar with the concept of iterating QR to find the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$, and at every iteration, I will have access to the contents of $A$, $Q_i$, and $R_i$ for $i\geq 1$.

I was wondering if there's a convenient way to find the eigenvectors, rather than solving $(A-\lambda_i I)v = 0$ for each $\lambda_i$?

Comment: Try posting this on [SciComp](http://www.scicomp.stackexchange.com)